# Redirecting Deleted pages to Homepage

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect

Hey I have Been trying to Redirect All deleted pages to the Homepage, But some of the pages are not redirecting like https://nitmeghalaya.in/nitm_web/fp/faculty_profile.php?fid=077 & https://nitmeghalaya.in/nitm_web/Tsubmenu.php?Tsubtab=21
I tried Redirecting Through Nginx using the Following

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
error_page 404 https://nitmeghalaya.in/
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Can you guys please help me out

Comment: These are PHP pages, so they are handled by a different `location` block. If you are using FastCGI, you will need to set [`fastcgi_intercept_errors on;`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors) and you will need to move your `error_page` statement into `server` scope.

Comment: hi can you please give directions so that i could do that